# glDatePicker 2 - data from Asp file

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm using glDatePicker 2, I wanted to modify the script to update the dates "selectableDateRange" from an ASP file that takes data from a datanbase ACCES.

example:
http://www.tuttoisole.it/public/aldo/a.htm

asp file:
http://www.tuttoisole.it/public/aldo/calendario.asp

asp file returns the following value:
[ { from: new Date(2013, 2, 1), to: new Date(2013, 2, 10) },{ from: new Date(2013, 2, 19), to: new Date(2013, 2, 22) } ]

but it does not work.

could you help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Aldo,   did you find your solution yet?? i am struggling same problems here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, I needed to update few options for it.

From their documentation

```
// This example updates some options (calling render will re-generate the calendar)
$.extend(myDatePicker.options,
{
    cssName: 'darkneon',
    allowMonthSelect: false,
    allowYearSelect: false
});
myDatePicker.render();

// If the calendar is not set to showAlways=true, you can force it to show by calling the show() function
myDatePicker.show();
```